# My Compute Engine VM has no external IP. What do other servers see?

Tags: google-compute-engine

My Google Cloud Compute Engine VM Instance claims to have no external IP address in the settings.

When I run the following code, I get an IP address.

```
response = requests.get('http://jsonip.com')
ip = response.json()['ip']
print('Your public IP is:', ip)

>>> Your public IP is: x.x.x.x  <-- Masking the IP address for security reasons
```

What address is returned? Is this just a non-static IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host is seeing the IP address for the Google Cloud NAT Gateway configured for the VPC. If a VPN is configured and is the default route, the host will see the router's IP address.

Google Cloud NAT Gateways use a static public IP address.

VPNs use whatever is configured and could be a single public static IP address or a group of IP addresses.